# Need an exposed filter field as select box with values like "Last x days" etc

Tags: views, 7

I'm trying to filter my nodes on the basis of last 7 days & last 30 days but the below code is not working for me when I tried this in my custom module, its working as a conversion for text-field to select but not working as a filter

```
function dreamzen_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $fromdate = &$form['created'];
    $fromdate['#type'] = 'select';
    $fromdate['#options'] = array(
      'All' => 'All',
      'Last 7 days' => '-7 days',
      'Last months' => '-30 days',
    );
    $fromdate['#default_value'] = '';
    $fromdate['#size'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: i think so you can achieve it through group filter.

Comment: @Humanlove How using group filter?

Comment: Can check this : 

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/how-to-combine-views-exposed-filter-with-search/76135#76135

Comment: @DhrubajyotiSaha Is it possible for you to help me with the merging of the two codes?

Answer (score 0):

are you checking, value is equal to '-7 days', it must match to the value of select box.

Hope this may help full.

Comment: "it must match to the value of select box?" Sorry but I didn't got it, can you please elaborate it?