# How to prevent result from being displayed when user selects search/apply

Tags: views

I created a "view" on my site with 3 exposed filters (One for "name", the other for "occupation" and the last for "location") to allow users search/filter for other users on my site.

On page load, no results are displayed. However, if I simply select search/apply (without inputting any search string), it displays results.

Please, how can i resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Am using views to display and filter. I want to ensure that no user information is displayed when a user clicks the search button, except he/she has entered a value into the exposed filter fields. Presently if I simply click "search" all users in my database is displayed. Thanks.

Comment: By 'no user information' you mean no results, empty list or "no results" text? That should be easy to set in filter settings.

Comment: Please can you explain further. I have 3 exposed filters. One for "name", the other for "occupation" and the last for "location". As it is, when a user clicks the search button, (without inputting any value into the 3 filter fields) all the users in my database is displayed. So now please, which of the 3 filters will I set and to what. Thanks!

Comment: If you make filter required, can you still get the result if user does not filter? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Mołot I think he wants to not show anything until there's something present in the exposed filters fields. I think it's a tricky question, and it's probably not in the scope of Filters to do that, I know if you use "Contextual Filters" you are able to set "Display 'No results'" if filter value is not present.

Comment: Basically, I believe a way the inial question can be further improved is by specific questions.

Comment: Basically, I believe a way the initial question can be further improved, is through specific follow up questions. I will give it another try: The problem I have is like a user clicking search on a search engine. This particular user has not entered any "search string"........probably he just clicks "search" out of curiosity. The result he gets is, all related information in the database is displayed to this curious user. That is the problem I have with this particular view. Please note that the information is not displayed before he clicks search but after. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to advanced settings of the view, you can set the exposed form settings to input required.

Another option if you are making use of the [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), there's a [patch](https://drupal.org/node/1447730) for it which adds 'input required' option/functionality,

Answer (score 0):

In D7, if we make the exposed filters be 'Required', we can avoide displaying default result list. But it will require you to set some default value for the exposed filter(s) out of the options 'Is equal to, Is not equal to, Regular expression etc'. Possibly the below post will help you :

[How to combine views exposed filter with search?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/how-to-combine-views-exposed-filter-with-search/76135#76135)

Keep the exposed filter(s) as not Required.

Here, you need to also check for a condition in your code that (considering all the exposed filters are mandatory be set to some value, as you have expected) the url parameter(s) have values, I mean it should have a format like 'http://sitename.com/test_path?title=test_title' (Not like 'http://sitename.com/test_path?title=').

Hope it helps