# Is there a way to include taxonomy terms and nodes in a search?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, search

I'm trying to make the search for my site gather results based on nodes and taxonomy terms.

To give an example of what I'm trying to do, say that I have content nodes set up for my products and have taxonomy terms based on colors associated with the nodes. If I search for "computer", results seem to be all nodes with "computer" in the title, which is good. If I search for "black computer", no results are returned. I want to be able to search for "black computer" and have results return all nodes that have computer in the node title and are associated with the taxonomy term "black".

FYI, I currently have the search index set to index nodes and am using a view to override the search. I'm using Drupal 7.23.

Comment: @Bala, By mistake, you have linked the same question in the comment.

Comment: Instead take a look at this you can play with this approach or at least you will get ideas http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/how-to-combine-views-exposed-filter-with-search

Comment: @Bala thanks for the help. I was able to achieve what I was talking about by using Commerce Search API, which can be found here: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api. To note, I'm using Drupal Commerce.