# Views filter has taxonomy term in whole vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm trying to use the "has taxonomy term" filter in a view together with Views Populate filters (https://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate).

The taxonomy filter has not to be exposed because the exposed filter is the one created with Populate filters.

The site admin continuosly add new term to the vocabulary.

Consequently I cannot fill the "is one of" setting for the "has taxonomy term" filter.

I would need some settings like: if the term is in the vocabulary.

Any idea?

It seems strange to me that you cannot use the same input field to search for example in title and in a term reference field.

thank you in advance

Comment: check if the video tutorial link helps you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/how-to-combine-views-exposed-filter-with-search/87387#87387

Comment: thank you, but that video does not answer to my question. I can use populate filters module, the problem is how to include a filter for "term reference field" if the related vocabulary is not fixed, but its values grow continuosly.

Answer (score 1):

I've reached this question while looking for something similar and couldn't find anything relevant. Yet, after searching trough views options, I've managed to achieve something I think is the easiest workaround to our mutual issue, which is why I'm resurrecting this question.

First things first, I've created a `View` to show all the  `taxonomy terms` of certain vocabulary and replaced the output as a link to, say, `/disciplines/[Term ID]`. Afterwards, I've created a `view` to replace the taxonomy display page and defined the term id as a contextual filter to the url(using the `%` replacement). Now every time the admin creates a new taxonomy term, the first `view` will always redirect to the second one with all the good stuff `Views` can offer.